# When using map::erase() "error: passing 'const ***' as 'this' argument of '***' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]" reported

Tags: c++, iterator, erase, qualifiers

I'm implementing the following method to delete an element from an associative table (`map`) with `map::erase()`:

```
//Method in gestion.cpp
void Gestion::EliminateObject(string nomobjetg) const{

    auto it = objectname.find(nameobjectg);

    if (it == objectname.end())
        cout << "Object not found!" << endl;
    else
        objectname.erase(it); //The error is reported in this line
}
```

In the header I have defined the following:

```
//gestion.h
#include "objects.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

typedef std::shared_ptr<Objects> ObjPtr;

typedef map<string, ObjPtr> Objectmap;

class Gestion
{
private:
     Objectmap objectname;

public:
    Gestion(Objectmap objectname, Groupmap groupname);
    virtual ~Gestion() {}
    virtual void EliminateObject(string nameobjectg) const;
};
```

Where `ObjPtr` is a virtual pointer of objects of type `Objects`.

When I compile I get this error:

```
error: passing ‘const Objectmap {aka const std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<Objects> >}’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::erase(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::shared_ptr<Objects>; _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<Objects> > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<Objects> > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<Objects> > >]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         objectname.erase(it);
```

Why is this line reporting this error? I've seen some other posts with this type of error but in those cases the root cause of the problem is related to how the method is declared (`const`). In this case the method involved in the problem is `erase` and I cannot modify it.

Comment: Unrelated, but you probably want to pass `nomobjetg` by const-reference instead of by value. That is `void Gestion::EliminateObject(const string& nomobjetg)`. If that is a std::string, it will do a wasteful string copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void Gestion::EliminateObject(string nomobjetg) **const**

You are trying to modify `objectname` with your call to `objectname.erase(it)`, and a `const` function will not let you do that, unless `objectname` is **mutable**.

Remove const:

```
void Gestion::EliminateObject(string nomobjetg)
```

or

Make `objectname` mutable

```
mutable Objectmap objectname;
```

Comment: thanks! for the first option do you suggest to change `const` by `*`? Why just eliminating `const` wouldn't solve the problem?

Comment: The * was a typo, I've fixed it now... Yes, I would just remove const. Mutable is for some specific cases, and before using it u should make sure what you need is a mutable data member...